# I am not able to change my Metamask account due to 3 lines of code in the below App.js code from line 25-27

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, react, smart-contract

Whenever I am compiling my code using the line 25-27 then I am not able to change my metamask account.

The 3 lines have been highlighted below.

```
const realEstate = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].realEstate.address, RealEstate, provider)
    const totalSupply = await realEstate.totalSupply()
    const homes = []
```

Can you please tell me the error.

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

// Components
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Home from "./components/Home";

// ABIs
import RealEstate from "./abis/RealEstate.json";
import Escrow from "./abis/Escrow.json";

// Config
import config from "./config.json";

function App() {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState()
  const [escrow, setEscrow] = useState()
  const [account, setAccount] = useState();
  const [homes, setHomes] = useState([]);
  const loadBlockChainData = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    setProvider(provider);
    const network = await provider.getNetwork()
    // const realEstate = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].realEstate.address, RealEstate, provider)
    // const totalSupply = await realEstate.totalSupply()
    // const homes = []

    // for(var i=1;i<= totalSupply; i++){
    //   const uri = await realEstate.tokenURI(i)
    //   const response = await fetch(uri)
    //   const metadata = await response.json()
    //   homes.push(metadata)
    // }
    // setHomes(homes);
    // console.log(homes);

    const escrow = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].escrow.address, Escrow, provider)
    setEscrow(escrow);

    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged',async()=>{
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts'
      });
      const account = ethers.utils.getAddress(accounts[0])
      setAccount(account)
    })
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadBlockChainData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} />
      <Search/>
      <div className="cards__section">
        <h3>Homes for you!</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <div className="cards">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card__image">
              <img alt="Home" src=""/>
            </div>
            <div className="card__info">
              <h4>1 ETH</h4>
              <p>
                <strong>1</strong> bds |
                <strong>2</strong> ba |
                <strong>3</strong> sqft
              </p>
              <p>1234 Elm Street</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error its to save users from losing their credits over the wrong network if you don't have your deployment working on that chain.

It is due to the `config[network.chainId]` parameter.

Here, you are configuring the chain (blockchain network) you want the user to work with.
Try passing the address directly.

Comment: I have passed the address config[network.chainId].realEstate.address here, What else can I do?

Comment: Try realEstate.address. I usually do it that way.

Comment: I tried that but still it's not working any other way?

Comment: Can you print the output of console.log(realEstate)?